# How can I prove that this implication is true?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, definition

I feel stupid posting such a question here where people are solving differential equations and such. But I have just started working on discrete math and even though I have studied implications I still can't solve any of the examples that my teacher gave me.

for example: $4\left|a\right. \implies 4\left|a^2\right.$.

I know that $a = 4k$,
so I thought $a^2 = (4k)^2$.
But it's not correct and I don't know what to do.

I asked my friend and his answer was $a^2 = 4\left(4k^2\right)$

I don't understand anything in this answer and I don't know how to write $4\left|a^2\right.$ in the same way as $4\left|a\right.$ which was $a=4k$.

Comment: This is the same answer, since $(4k)^2 = 4(4k^2)$. Basically your friend just factorized by $4$ to make appear the divisibility by $4$ more clearly. But your calculations are the same.

Comment: The title you used is poorly chosen, it's not descriptive at all. Please try to describe the problem in the title.

Answer (score 1):

You and your friend are both correct. Let's start from the beginning. If $4|a$, then this means that for some integer $k$, we have $a=4k$. Now you want to prove that $4$ divides $a^2$. Notice
$$a^2=(4k)^2=4k\cdot 4k=4\cdot 4\cdot k\cdot k=4(4k^2).$$
So $a^2$ is a multiple of $4$, and we conclude $4|a^2$.

Comment: How is the inversion?

Comment: You mean "converse"? It is not true, because $4$ divides $4=2^2$, however $4$ does not divide $2$. In other words, if $4$ divides a number $a$, then $4$ divides $a^2$, but if $4$ divides $a^2$, then $4$ need not divide $a$. Is this clear?

Comment: Yes! But how can I prove it mathematically? In the same way that I did for the first implication?

Comment: I mean, you can't prove something that's not true, so you probably mean "how do I show that the converse is false?". A counterexample suffices, and I gave you one already.

Comment: Isn't this correct? a^2=4k also a=√4k which is 2√k 
and 2√k = 4k (is not true)

Comment: No. That won't work. What you are trying to prove right there is that for any $a^2$ divisible by $4$, $a$ is always not divisible by $4$, and that isn't true -- for example, let $a=4$. Then $a^2=16$ is divisible by $4$ and $a$ is also divisible by $4$.

Comment: why isn't that true? If a is 10 then it's not true because 100/4= 25   but 10/4 is not evenly dividable.

Comment: I think you are getting lost in incorrect logic--try reading the comments again carefully or ask your professor if there is one.